# Adjust the number of limited acess in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, throttling

I need an advise

I want to limit the number of access to Djano server. In settings.py, I can configure the number of access in DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES, for example:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle',
        'rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'anon': '100/day',
        'user': '1000/day'
    }
}
```

but now I want to change the number of access via HTML interface. Can I do it? If possible, what do I need to do?

Thanks.

Comment: do you want to set throttle rate dynamically ?

Comment: yes, I can change erverytime